# Why don't files automatically get checked out from VSS when I edit them?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-sourcesafe, vcs-checkout

This is driving me crazy and has resulted in lost work (not much, at least).

Normally, when I edit a file in Visual Studio, it's supposed to automatically check that file out in source safe. On multi-project solutions (e.g., web app with class libraries), sometimes none of the files in one project would automatically get checked out, though exiting & reloading visual studio may fix that problem temporarily. Furthermore, project files are never automatically checked out. Whenever I add/remove code files, I have to remember to explicitly check out the project file as well (otherwise we'll have issues with code files not showing up in the solution explorer, or trying to load non-existing files).

We're using VS-2008 and VSS 2005. Do you have any idea how I might fix this? There are no more visual-studio updates/fixes on Microsoft Update.

Comment: Although it's probably not an option for you, but for me all this pain is gone in our projects where we are using SVN instead of VSS. Unfortunately there are still some projects which are not migrated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the files are read-only, or VS won't be able to tell that they are version controlled (or, at least that's what it uses to determine it). You can tell VSS to set itself up so getting the latest version places the files RW on disk.

There may be other problems here, but that's what comes to mind first. My advice (that I took myself) is to migrate to SVN or an alternative. Losing work is unacceptable.

Comment: Sorry, but there's no chance of us migrating to SVN, despite how much I love the Tortoise front-end. I didn't know about the read-only thing though, I'll try that.

Comment: same here - until we lost a file. Try checking in a very large file across a WAN, maybe from home. You will lose data quicker than you thought possible. (though you'll never know until you check it out and realise its corrupt). That was unacceptable even to my F/OSS-hating boss!