# Visual Studio 2010 is not checking out code from VSS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I have a project that I have been using VSS source control from the VS Pending Checkins tab. This has been working until recently. Now when I make a change to the code, I do not get an entry in the Pending Checkins tab.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294509/visual-studio-isnt-tracking-changes-or-checking-out-files-from-source-control) article, but did not see a Go Online option either when right-clicking on the solution or under File -> Source Control. Probably because that person was using TFS rather than VSS.

I tried breaking the source control links and creating a new tree, but it still didn't check out automatically when I made changes. I have been using the Check Out For Edit option, and then checking in, but this gets all classes whether I make changes or not. I use source control in VS because the list makes it simple to determine whether I need to check something in or not.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this may have stopped working with this project. It is still working in other projects. I do have "Check out automatically" selected for On Save and On Edit. Allow checked-in items to be edited is not checked, nor are any of the other options under Source Control -> Environment.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

UPDATE: I just added a new class to the solution, and that class appears under pending checkins. However, I also made several changes to other classes, and none of them are appearing under checkins.

Comment: +1 for you out of compassion, because you still need to deal with SourceSafe. I thought it was dead since 8 years.

Comment: It *is* dead for many years. Even Microsoft uses Git these days.

Answer (score 0):

I too rely on SourceSafe via Visual Studio to automatically check out files.  But it usually just works by default although with certain assumptions you need to know that I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783770/1998025) post which explains the risky methodology:

If you Get all files without checking them out then the files will be read only as you can see in Windows Explorer properties.  Then, when you type your first edit to any file, VS/ VSS first checks for the read-only attribute on that file.  If it is read only then the file will be automatically checked out (this is the default option).  Then, when you are ready to check-in a set of files, VS will show you all “Pending Check-ins” and you can check them in as a set.

I have relied on this for years as it has been working great for me in our environment until a few weeks ago when many of my source files lost their read only attribute somehow.  So without read-only, some of the files were not getting checked out and therefore not getting checked in.  And that’s really hard to detect until your hard-drive crashes and you try to build from another machine!

And I found a method [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/4395430.aspx) to fix the read only attributes:

> check in all files that were edited (used VSS to find out which files where 
>   changed [using differences] even though VS did not checked them out). Then did a Get Latest with 
>   overwrite of local files and made sure the "Keep writable" checkbox was not 
>   checked.